# LineNumberReader.readLine() if query not behaving correctly

Tags: java, readline

I am trying to Find out how often the line "character" is in a .txt file
I tried This:

```
String line;
int characterAmount;
characterAmountReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(filename));
while ((line = characterAmountReader.readLine()) != null) {
    if(line == "<character>") {
        characterAmount++;
    }
}
```

but for some reason it doesn't work : /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are comparing String using `==` and not the method `equals()`

See the full explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/5914654)

To be simple `==` compare instances. Since `line` and `"<character>"` are not the same instance of the class String, it always return false. Using the `equals()` method compare the value, in this case it should return true when the line value is `"<character>"`.